# Spring IT test fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, querydsl

I have added a new querydsl controller method in my spring (not spring boot) application.

```
@GetMapping("/watcher")
@ResponseBody
public List<Watcher> getWatchers(final Predicate predicate) {
  return repo.findAll(predicate);
}
```

I have also added the following annotation in my WebMvcConfigurer implementation:

```
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
```

The application works with this new endpoint as intented. I would now like to add a Spring IT test to test this new feature.

This is the test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  mvc.perform(get("/watcher"));
}
```

The test class contains the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringITConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Other tests are present in the same class, and perform() works for those, but it's the first time I'm adding a test to a querydsl controller.

The test fails with `No primary or default constructor found for interface com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate`.

I tried adding the annotation `@EnableSpringDataWebSupport` to my test, but it doesn't change anything.

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679551/junit-no-primary-or-default-constructor-found-for-interface-com-querydsl-core-t ??

Comment: Yes, it says to add the annotation `EnableSpringDataWebSupport` to the test as well, which I did as mentioned in my question, but it doesn't change the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your `@ContextConfiguration` and replace it  with `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = YOUR_MAIN_APP_CLASS)` to bootstrap all the needed querydsl repositories, and also the correct jackson mapper for your predicate class.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I do not use spring boot. I do not have a main class.